# Call client script from button with submit behaviour false?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How do I call a client script function from a server side button click(with submit behaviour set to false) .

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    lbDateTime.Text=System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"success","saveSuccess()");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the OnClientClick attribute of the Button like

```
OnClientClick="saveSuccess(); return false;"
```

this way you keep the sumbit behaviour to false, and you also call the client script function.

Also, if you want to do this via server side code you can add this to your Page_Load

```
Button4.Attributes["OnClientClick"] = "saveSuccess(); return false;";
```

However, if you want to call the script after the "save" has completed, and you are using asynchronous jobs, and an UpdatePanel, then you should call

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "savescript", "saveSuccess();", true);
```

after the asynch job has finished, and the data have been saved.

Comment: thanks Nikos,I am using this approach because I want to call the script only after a certain event has occured server side (Like some records saved in the database)

Comment: You mean you want the 'saveSuccess()' script to be called, only if the records are saved? Will the button (button4) need to call the function that will save the records? If so, then the button should probably not have the submit behaviour to false. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Hi, Button4 will save the records server side. On success, it would call the client script which would display a status message via a function. Isn't there any way round this ?

Comment: Well, you have to submit the request with button4, so submit behaviour should be set to true. When the "save" is finished, then you can use ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"success","saveSuccess()"); If you use and UpdatePanel then you should use the ScriptManager to register the script.

Comment: Also, if the "save" takes long, and you want to continue working while the application saves the records, you should consider using a BackgroundWorker, however I am not sure if this is the case.

Comment: I have my button outside the update panel, requirements are such that I cannot include the button inside the update panel nor change the submit mode to true.

Comment: I am disabling the button on postback & enabling it when Asynch request is completed. I have to set the submit behaviour to false to re enable the button otherwise it would make a postback. As it is outside the update panel.

Comment: If my understanding of the situation is correct, then you should probably call ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "scriptname", "saveSuccess();", true) when the Asynch request is completed, and you re-enable the button? Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks Nikos, you are correct. Problem was solved by using scriptManager.StartupScript. Thumbs up =)

Comment: Glad I've helped! I'll edit my response to assist any other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "success", "saveSuccess()", true);
```